# Dynamic Percentile Lookup

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to lookup a dynamic percentile in a list (Or you could think of it as a LARGE function in Excel).  Below is an idea of what I am looking at. (Please forgive the non-contemporary coding practices as I am not a programmer)

I first build a Temporary Table which houses the information I want.  This includes 'Miles' and is ordered by 'Miles' DESC.  I then calculate the @Lookup_Position which is always less than or equal to the @Row_Count in the Temporary Table.  For example,

```
@Row_Count      @Lookup_Position
0               0
1               0
5               2
50              7
```

I understand that looking up the 0'th row may be a problem but I figure I'll cross that bridge when I get there.  My problem comes in when attempting to lookup the @Lookup_Position'th row in the Table.

```
DECLARE @Row_Count INT
DECLARE @Lookup_Position INT
DECLARE @Lookedup_Miles DECIMAL

SELECT --Create Temporary Table
INTO #Temporary_Table
FROM --Other Tables
ORDER BY 'Miles' DESC

SELECT @Row_Count = COUNT ( TT.* )
    ,@Lookup_Position = CASE WHEN @RowCount = 1 THEN 0 
        ELSE SQRT ( @Row_Count ) END
FROM #Temporary_Table TT

--Below is where I believe my problem lies since all 
  --other variables return what I expect
SELECT TOP @Lookup_Position
    @Lookedup_Miles = MIN ( TT.Miles )
FROM #Temporary_Table TT
GROUP BY 'Miles'
ORDER BY 'Miles' DESC
```

In my mind, the last line of code (`ORDER BY 'Miles' DESC` ) seems superfluous but I am sure.  I am working in SQL Management Studio.

I am returned an output from the 'Miles' field for @Lookedup_Miles but it is not the @Lookup_Position'th largest value. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: SQL 2012 (and above) has a function for that

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-cont-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

I am expecting something like this:

```
SELECT TOP (1) @Lookedup_Miles = TT.Miles
FROM #Temporary_Table TT
WHERE TT.Row_Count <= @Lookup_Position
ORDER BY TT.Row_Count DESC;
```

However, your code is filled with numerous errors.  You cannot use strings in `ORDER BY` or `GROUP BY` clauses -- that generates an error.  Ordering a temporary table won't make a difference, unless you have an identity column.  And it is unclear why a temporary table is even necessary.

Comment: Good to know.  Thank you.  The Temporary Table is used because I use this same subquery several times.  The subquery is a bit slow so I dont want to run it more than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Gordon pointed out, if you are looking to get a specific ("nth") row from a table, `TOP n` is not the way to do it.

Look into the relatively new `OFFSET` and `FETCH` arguments to the `ORDER BY` [clause in SQL Server.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)   They are the right way to get an "nth" row of a table.